# In JDBC, csv format is not delimited correctly due to a comma coming in a field/column of a table

Tags: java, csv, jdbc

```
import java.sql.*;


public class Voucher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
                 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                 String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:user/pwd@IP:PORT:DB";

                 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);

                String query = "SELECT CIRCLENAME,CALLINGVALUE,GRACEPERIOD,MINOFUSAGE,MRP,PROCESSINGFEE,SERVICETAX,VALIDITY from AM_PREPAID_VOUCHER_COUPONS A, AM_CIRCLE B WHERE A.CIRCLEID=B.CIRCLEID order by b.CIRCLENAME asc";






                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                                System.out.println("CIRCLENAME,CALLINGVALUE,GRACEPERIOD,MINOFUSAGE,MRP,PROCESSINGFEE,SERVICETAX,VALIDITY");
                while (rs.next())
                {   

                 String CIRCLENAME = rs.getString("CIRCLENAME");
                 String CALLINGVALUE = rs.getString("CALLINGVALUE");
                 String GRACEPERIOD = rs.getString("GRACEPERIOD");
                 String MINOFUSAGE = rs.getString("MINOFUSAGE");
                 String MRP = rs.getString("MRP");
                 String PROCESSINGFEE = rs.getString("PROCESSINGFEE");
                 String SERVICETAX = rs.getString("SERVICETAX");
                 String VALIDITY = rs.getString("VALIDITY");


                    System.out.println(CIRCLENAME+ "," +CALLINGVALUE+ "," +
                    GRACEPERIOD+ "," +MINOFUSAGE+ "," +MRP+ "," +PROCESSINGFEE+ "," +
                    SERVICETAX+ "," +VALIDITY);

             }

                conn.close();
        }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                }

            }

}
```

Value in column - CALLINGVALUE is "49 TT, 5 days" due to which column values are printed correctly in a csv format. How to handle this comma within a column?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to export data in a comma separated format but one column in database table ( column name - CALLINGVALUE), has a comma in it ( eg: 49 TT, 5 days) due to which a single column value is getting split into two columns. How to export the values as such into a csv format?

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose each field between quotes, but you would have a problem if the data contains quote character, in which case, you should double them.

Otherwise, You can use a CSV library. That's what I would do.